# Nondifferentiablity of $1/\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus

Consider $f(x)=1/\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$ then find the number of points of non differentiablity of $f(x)$ in $(0,3\pi)$.

Clearly, $f(x)$ is not differentiable  for $x=0$, $ \pi$, $2 \pi$,
since $f(x)$is not defined for these values of x.
After drawing the graph of $\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$, I found that the there are 3 sharp point, which are x=$\pi/2$, $3\pi/2$, $5\pi/2$. However, does it imply that $f(x)$ is also non differentiable at these points?

Comment: That is probably the reason why the graphical rendering was as such.

Comment: Just to note, $0$ is not in $(0,3\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is non-differentiable at those points too. To verify this just take the left hand derivative and right hand derivative at those points, from the piece-wise definition of the function (each part would come out to be linear).
For example, at $\frac {\pi}{2}$, left hand derivative is negative while the right hand derivative is positive. So it's impossible for them to be equal. Similar case for the other two points.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that the derivative is discontinuous. A good first step is to take the derivative.
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\arcsin(\sin x)}$$
The derivative is (exercise)
$$f'(x)=\frac{-\cos(x)}{\arcsin(\sin x)^2\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}$$
Now we use the identity
$$1-\sin^2 x=\cos^2 x$$
And, more importantly
$$\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$$
Hence
$$f'(x)=-\frac{\cos x}{|\cos x|}\frac{1}{\arcsin(\sin x)^2}$$
Which using the sign function is
$$f'(x)=-\operatorname{sgn}(\cos x)\cdot \frac{1}{f(x)^2}$$
Now I ask you - when is $\operatorname{sgn}$ discontinuous?